Cursor Focus is lost to unknown on Windows 11, no matter what I am doing
The last 72 hours have been driving me mad, it does not matter what I am doing on my computer, the focus of the cursor keeps changing to an unknown.
I think this may have started after applying the latest Windows update. (2024-10 Cumulative Update Preview for Windows 11 Version 23H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5044380))
Looking at previous posts about similar issues, I found this post, in which @ClioCJS kindly made available an application that outputs to the console the filename of each process that takes focus.
I have run that application which works perfectly, however, in my situation, it's not able to identify the issue :(.
Screenshot of focus monitor
Any help with this would be amazing as this is rendering my computer unusable!
P.S. My first post of hopefully many to contribute to a great site,

Process Monitor might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon . It captures date-time for all processes, so note when cursor hides. Also look to settings to automatically hide cursor when typing or watching video: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/turn-on-or-off-hide-pointer-while-typing-in-windows-11.12422/ and https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-hide-mouse-cursor/
